# Eclipse\Aptana code completion is unreadable

Tags: eclipse, aptana

I'm having an issue where the text in the code completion dialog is unreadable. For whatever reason the foreground is the same as the background. I have tried finding the right colors to change in the preferences but with no success.[image]

Comment: I have the same problem and found this here.  Any luck fixing it?

Answer (score 2):

It was pulling the colors from the default system theme selected in Ubuntu. It appears that Aptana doesn't allow one to override the system colors for that dialog.

Answer (score 2):

Actually, there is a solution for this problem. The first possibility is to change the Aptana theme at Window - Preferences - Aptana Studio - Themes. IMHO, the "Bespin" theme's quite nice. The second possibility is to change the colors system-wide using Ubuntu's appearance settings for tooltips:

[image]